# Interpolation and estimation of data in R

Tags: r

Here are my data showing the cardiopulmonary evolution during an acute exercise with gaz exchange analysis. As we can see, when I report data according the relative percentage of peak power (`percent_power`), the percentage doesn't correspond between each individuals, because, of course, everyone has a different peak.

Then, I would like to create an interpolation for each individual to estimate specific percentages (e.g. 25%, 50%, 75%) for each individual, and put in a column. Consequently, each variable should be estimated as well and should correspond to the new estimated 25, 50, 75 % of `percent_power`.

Thank you very much all for your help,

```
            id power  training     hr    fr    VE  absVO2    VCO2  PETCO2     VES     QC     IC    WCI    RVSi     RVS     VTD     FE body_mass percent_absVO2 percent_power    relVO2  percent_relVO2 group temps
1  AC12-PRD-C1    25    linear  88.75 22.75 22.75 0.73900 0.66700 39.2925  88.650  8.025  3.975  4.825 1768.75  876.00 143.025 62.050      84.0       49.34068      21.73913  8.797619        49.34068   CHD     1
2  AC12-PRD-C1    40    linear  93.25 23.00 23.75 0.81975 0.71500 39.6200  87.375  8.050  3.975  4.825 1759.50  871.75 141.625 61.725      84.0       54.73210      34.78261  9.758929        54.73210   CHD     1
3  AC12-PRD-C1    55    linear  99.75 22.75 26.75 0.95125 0.85400 41.4100  93.375  9.175  4.550  5.525 1540.50  763.00 150.325 62.100      84.0       63.51193      47.82609 11.324405        63.51193   CHD     1
4  AC12-PRD-C1    70    linear 109.75 23.00 32.50 1.07525 1.04700 42.0150  93.825 10.025  4.925  6.000 1414.25  700.50 145.750 64.375      84.0       71.79102      60.86957 12.800595        71.79102   CHD     1
5  AC12-PRD-C1    85    linear 118.75 22.75 39.50 1.19900 1.25125 41.8425  97.375 11.225  5.575  6.750 1260.75  624.50 148.975 65.325      84.0       80.05341      73.91304 14.273810        80.05341   CHD     1
6  AC12-PRD-C1   100    linear 127.00 26.00 48.25 1.34575 1.51850 41.0950 100.900 12.550  6.225  7.525 1127.75  558.75 154.225 65.475      84.0       89.85144      86.95652 16.020833        89.85144   CHD     1
7  AC12-PRD-C1   115    linear 135.75 28.00 55.75 1.49775 1.76025 40.7275 104.475 13.950  6.875  8.375 1014.00  502.25 157.975 66.250      84.0      100.00000     100.00000 17.830357       100.00000   CHD     1
8  AC12-PRD-C2    25    linear  84.25 20.50 20.75 0.67625 0.59950 38.9575 102.700  8.650  4.275  5.575 1775.00  879.50 216.450 48.350      84.8       40.10378      17.24138  7.974646        40.10378   CHD     2
9  AC12-PRD-C2    40    linear  89.25 20.50 23.25 0.73350 0.66225 38.5500 111.625  9.725  4.800  6.250 1567.75  776.75 217.800 51.825      84.8       43.49889      27.58621  8.649764        43.49889   CHD     2
10 AC12-PRD-C2    55    linear  96.25 22.25 26.75 0.83550 0.77500 38.3350 101.300  9.325  4.625  6.000 1619.75  802.75 202.700 50.350      84.8       49.54781      37.93103  9.852594        49.54781   CHD     2
11 AC12-PRD-C2    70    linear 102.25 21.75 32.50 1.06250 1.01550 39.6525 103.550 10.350  5.125  6.625 1459.00  723.00 194.050 53.675      84.8       63.00964      48.27586 12.529481        63.00964   CHD     2
12 AC12-PRD-C2    85    linear 110.75 22.25 37.75 1.18075 1.19225 40.1300 100.825 10.650  5.275  6.825 1424.00  705.25 194.250 51.900      84.8       70.02224      58.62069 13.923939        70.02224   CHD     2
13 AC12-PRD-C2   100    linear 118.25 23.00 42.75 1.35100 1.40300 41.1500 108.950 12.375  6.100  7.950 1225.50  606.75 197.325 55.175      84.8       80.11861      68.96552 15.931604        80.11861   CHD     2
14 AC12-PRD-C2   115    linear 129.25 24.75 51.25 1.50650 1.65650 40.7575 107.625 13.275  6.550  8.525 1133.50  561.50 201.225 53.525      84.8       89.34025      79.31034 17.765330        89.34025   CHD     2
15 AC12-PRD-C2   130    linear 136.25 26.50 58.75 1.57325 1.83200 39.6750 108.925 14.375  7.125  9.250 1045.75  518.25 196.025 55.675      84.8       93.29874      89.65517 18.552476        93.29874   CHD     2
16 AC12-PRD-C2   145    linear 147.50 29.75 70.00 1.68625 2.07350 38.1600 104.875 15.025  7.450  9.600 1010.75  500.75 185.400 56.825      84.8      100.00000     100.00000 19.885024       100.00000   CHD     2
17 AL13-PRD-C1    25 nonlinear  69.50 16.50 24.00 0.66125 0.58050 31.2275 101.825  7.175  3.500  4.450 2126.50 1037.25 220.850 48.550      85.5       41.36691      19.23077  7.733918        41.36691   CHD     1
18 AL13-PRD-C1    40 nonlinear  73.00 17.50 26.50 0.74850 0.66425 32.1025 107.850  7.775  3.775  4.850 1942.00  947.25 242.825 48.000      85.5       46.82515      30.76923  8.754386        46.82515   CHD     1
19 AL13-PRD-C1    55 nonlinear  83.25 15.50 29.00 0.85500 0.79425 33.6650 110.250  9.075  4.375  5.650 1706.00  832.50 233.500 47.325      85.5       53.48764      42.30769 10.000000        53.48764   CHD     1
20 AL13-PRD-C1    70 nonlinear  93.75 16.00 36.50 0.98450 0.99925 34.5325 114.650 10.425  5.075  6.525 1462.00  713.25 233.075 49.175      85.5       61.58899      53.84615 11.514620        61.58899   CHD     1
21 AL13-PRD-C1    85 nonlinear 104.50 16.00 44.75 1.14950 1.23475 34.4225 120.650 12.150  5.925  7.550 1249.25  609.25 233.575 51.775      85.5       71.91117      65.38462 13.444444        71.91117   CHD     1
22 AL13-PRD-C1   100 nonlinear 114.25 19.25 55.25 1.34650 1.48375 33.1800 115.250 12.775  6.275  7.975 1178.25  574.75 220.375 52.350      85.5       84.23522      76.92308 15.748538        84.23522   CHD     1
23 AL13-PRD-C1   115 nonlinear 125.25 20.75 63.75 1.45100 1.65775 32.6450 117.500 14.100  6.875  8.825 1095.25  534.25 236.575 50.200      85.5       90.77260      88.46154 16.970760        90.77260   CHD     1
24 AL13-PRD-C1   130 nonlinear 136.25 24.75 78.00 1.59850 1.89075 30.9000 119.150 15.575  7.600  9.700  968.25  472.25 231.075 51.600      85.5      100.00000     100.00000 18.695906       100.00000   CHD     1
25 AL13-PRD-C2    25 nonlinear  60.25 15.75 19.00 0.56950 0.46550 32.2575 154.625  9.450  4.700  6.075 1597.75  794.75 348.975 44.850      82.4       30.83378      15.62500  6.911408        30.83378   CHD     2
26 AL13-PRD-C2    40 nonlinear  63.25 14.25 19.50 0.63175 0.52325 33.5700 143.225  9.275  4.625  5.975 1631.75  811.50 326.325 44.575      82.4       34.20411      25.00000  7.666869        34.20411   CHD     2
27 AL13-PRD-C2    55 nonlinear  72.75 15.75 25.00 0.82600 0.69925 34.4600 147.350 10.175  5.075  6.525 1497.25  744.75 312.475 47.950      82.4       44.72117      34.37500 10.024272        44.72117   CHD     2
28 AL13-PRD-C2    70 nonlinear  79.00 15.50 30.75 0.94525 0.86850 34.9675 153.575 11.925  5.925  7.675 1257.00  625.25 271.525 56.625      82.4       51.17759      43.75000 11.471481        51.17759   CHD     2
29 AL13-PRD-C2    85 nonlinear  88.25 16.00 37.50 1.15050 1.08025 35.6175 155.200 13.325  6.625  8.550 1127.00  560.50 282.300 54.975      82.4       62.29020      53.12500 13.962379        62.29020   CHD     2
30 AL13-PRD-C2   100 nonlinear  99.00 16.75 44.75 1.29925 1.31475 35.6475 154.150 14.775  7.325  9.500 1030.75  512.50 285.350 54.500      82.4       70.34380      62.50000 15.767597        70.34380   CHD     2
31 AL13-PRD-C2   115 nonlinear 107.00 18.00 50.00 1.39775 1.45600 36.0325 161.000 16.675  8.300 10.725  898.00  446.50 282.850 57.175      82.4       75.67677      71.87500 16.962985        75.67677   CHD     2
32 AL13-PRD-C2   130 nonlinear 118.50 21.00 61.50 1.55100 1.73675 34.8775 162.300 18.300  9.100 11.750  815.75  405.75 276.700 58.700      82.4       83.97401      81.25000 18.822816        83.97401   CHD     2
33 AL13-PRD-C2   145 nonlinear 128.25 24.25 74.75 1.71275 1.99100 33.3300 161.025 19.925  9.900 12.800  749.50  372.75 267.875 60.175      82.4       92.73146      90.62500 20.785801        92.73146   CHD     2
34 AL13-PRD-C2   160 nonlinear 142.50 29.00 90.50 1.84700 2.21650 30.9325 154.750 20.925 10.425 13.425  715.50  355.75 272.250 57.100      82.4      100.00000     100.00000 22.415049       100.00000   CHD     2
```

Comment: What have you tried or what do you think might work? The simplest opion I see would be to perform linear regression per individual with one or more explanatory variables, another are decision trees or even neural networks. If you are not sure how to work this with some sort of maschine learning possibly the [h2o](https://www.h2o.ai/) auto-ml functionality is a good point to start as it has a cran package for you to be able to work it directly from R

Comment: I have tried a linear regression but per group, not individual. If you could help me for that, it should very appreciated. I think it could be the best way

Comment: If I understood correctly, you would like to estimate the 25, 50, 75-th quantile for each (?) column (state which ones exactly), while grouping for the "id" variable?

Comment: Not exactly. I would like to estimate all value in every column based on the column ``percent_power`` for 25 %, 50 %, and 75 % of ``percent_power`` for each individual. At the moment, you can see that the column ``percent_power`` doesn't have 25, 50 and 75% for each individual. We have to make an interpolation. I hope it is clearer....